# jStree toggle_node Double Click Issue

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have a double click event on my nodes defined like so:

```
$('#tree').bind("dblclick.jstree", function  (event, data) {
      var NODE = $.jstree._focused().get_selected();
      nodeId = $(NODE).attr("id");
      type = $(NODE).attr("type");
      openNode(nodeId, type);
})
```

I also wanted to enable the ability to click on a node to toggle its children, so I added this to the types:

```
"default": {
    "select_node": function(e) {
      this.toggle_node(e);
      return true;
  }
}
```

But now when I double click a node, it also toggles it's children, which I don't want.  I only want to toggle on a single click.  Is this possible?

Comment: Can you providee jsfiddle sample? Did you try to use `.bind` for click instead of using types?